# sql calculate retention

Tags: sql, sqlite

how do I calculate retention rate in SQL to add as a column to my table

1. first day I had in Brazil 411 unique users
2. second day only 154 users came back (retention rate is 154/411)
3. third day only 115 came back again (115/154)
4. last day only 81 out of 98 users came back

   ```
    Country      Date  sum_views  distinct_user_ids
      Brazil  5/5/2016              3793           411
      Brazil  5/6/2016              1632           154
      Brazil  5/7/2016              1456           115
      Brazil  5/8/2016              1223            98
      Brazil  5/9/2016               993            81
      Canada  5/5/2016              6419           708
      Canada  5/6/2016              2649           235
      Canada  5/7/2016              2578           197
      Canada  5/8/2016              2024           151
      Canada  5/9/2016              1893           141
      United states  5/5/2016             13007          1438
      United states  5/6/2016              5755           522
      United states  5/7/2016              5502           419
      United states  5/8/2016              4915           362
      United states  5/9/2016              3713           284
   ```

output :

a column with retention rate

Comment: what do you want as a result?which dbms are you using?what does the input data look like? add all the relevant info to the question.

Comment: SQLite3, there is an example of the input, result is retention rate column inside the table

Comment: You should also include the output you want.

Comment: done, even though I think it can be concluded from the first sentence in my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the previous value for the denominator.  You can get that with a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*, tprev.distinct_user_ids,
       (t.distinct_user_ids / tprev.distinct_user_ids)
from t join
     t tprev
     on tprev.country = t.country and
        tprev.date = date(t.date, '-1 day');
```

Comment: can you explain ? where does table t2 comes from ?

Comment: @JimWest . . . The `t2` was a typo.

Comment: can you please explain your answer ?

Comment: @JimWest . . . It is joining back to the table to get the previous row.  That is used for the denominator.

Comment: This will only give you D1 retention right? If I need retention rates for other days, guess I have to do multiple joins?

Comment: @NicholasHumphrey . . . I would suggest that you ask a *new* question about your specific issue.